# Calculus question with optimization homework

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, derivatives

A piece of wire 30 m long is cut into two pieces. One piece is bent into a square and the other is bent into a circle.

(a) How much of the wire should go to the square to maximize the total area enclosed by both figures?  m

(b) How much of the wire should go to the square to minimize the total area enclosed by both figures?  m

This is What I have done so far:

$\pi r^2 +(30-r)^2$

$\frac{dy}{dx}= 2\pi r-2(30-r)$

$60=2\pi r-2r$
$60=r(2{\pi}-2)$
$30=r(\pi-1)$

$r= \frac{30}{\pi-1}$

$r=14.01$   I do not understand What I am meant to do with this number now.. Is it the answer to a or b? and how do I find the other.

Comment: Your first formula appears to be wrong.

Comment: Don't forget that there are always extrema on the boundary points.  That's *crucial* for that problem.

Comment: As reference to future viewers, there is more discussion of this problem (differing only as to the length of wire) here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127493/optimization-with-two-shapes?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $x$ meter of the 30 meters to form the circle, the radius of the circle is not $x$ but $\frac{x}{2\pi}$.  Then how long is the side of the square?  And don't forget the boundaries $x=0$ and $x=30$.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a fairly "standard" first-semester calculus textbook problem (if it isn't given for homework, it turns up on an exam), I thought I'd write something about it generally.

The problem usually asks for a length of wire $ \ L \ $ to be cut into two pieces, each one to be formed into a specified geometric figure; the typical choices are a square and a circle, or an equilateral triangle and a circle.  (As we'll see, the actual figures used don't affect the character of the solution.)  For these particular shapes, we have the relations

**square :**  $$ l_s \ = \ 4S \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ A_s \ = \ S^2 \ = \ \left( \frac{l_s}{4} \right)^2 \ = \ \frac{1}{16} \ l_s^2 \ \ ; $$

**equilateral triangle :**  $$ l_t \ = \ 3s \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ A_t \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}s^2 \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left( \frac{l_t}{3} \right)^2 \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{36} \ l_t^2  \ \ ; $$

**square :**  $$ l_c \ = \ 2 \pi \ r \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ A_c \ = \ \pi \ r^2 \ = \ \pi \left( \frac{l_c}{2 \pi} \right)^2 \ = \ \frac{1}{4 \pi} \ l_c^2\ \ . $$

The significant (and familiar) feature of these area functions is that they are always increasing with the length of the wire used to produce them and are always "concave upward"; they really only differ as to the constant of proportionality (what physicists call the "dimensionless geometric factor").

[image]
*area functions of  circular (blue), square (green), and equilateral-triangular (red) lengths of wire, with* $ \ 0 \ \le \ L \ \le \ 10 \ $

Upon cutting the length of wire $ \ L \ $ into two pieces, and, say, allocating the length $ \ x \ $ to the triangle or square and the remainder, $ \ L \ - \ x \ $ to the circle, we produce the area-sum functions

**square  +  circle :**  $$ \ \ A \ = \  \frac{1}{16} \ x^2 \ + \ \frac{1}{4 \pi} \ (L - x)^2  \ \ ; $$

**equilateral triangle + circle :**  $$ \ \ A \ = \  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{36} \ x^2 \ + \ \frac{1}{4 \pi} \ (L - x)^2  \ \ . $$

What we are interested in noting here is the *properties* of such area-sum functions.  For two wire shapes (they need not even be regular figures, but just simple closed curves) with "geometric factors"  $ \ F_1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ F_2 \ $ , the first two derivatives of the area-sum function are

$$ \ \frac{dA}{dx} \ = \ 2 \ F_1 \ x \ - \ 2 \ F_2 \ (L - x ) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \frac{d^2A}{dx^2} \ = \ 2 \ F_1  \ + \ 2 \ F_2 \ \ . $$

Since the geometric factors are necessarily positive, we will always have  $ \ \frac{d^2A}{dx^2} \ > \ 0 \ $ in such problems, so the extremal value of the area-sum in the interval $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ L \ $ is a **minimum** located as  $ \ x \ = \ \left( \frac{F_2}{F_1 + F_2} \right) \ L \ $ .  This will be true regardless of the choice for the two simple closed curves.

[image]
*the red, green, and blue curves are those appearing in the graph above, but with the circle area function "reversed" on the interval* $ \ 0 \ \le \ x \ \le \ L \ $ *to represent the circle being the "second" piece of wire; the greenish and violet curves represent the "square-and-circle" and "triangle-and-circle" area-sum functions, respectively*

What is often called the "extreme value theorem" tells us that a continuous function on a closed interval has an absolute maximum and an absolute minimum value.  Since the open interval $ \ 0 \ 
< \ x \ < \ L \ $ doesn't contain a maximum, we must look for the absolute maximum at one of the endpoints of the closed interval, $ \ x  \ = \ 0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ x \ = \ L \ $ .  But here, we can use another familiar fact (not readily established using only first-semester calculus) that a circle of a specified "perimeter" encloses the greatest possible area of any simple closed curve.  Hence, the solution for the **maximal enclosed area** is to use the *entire length* of wire (corresponding here to $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ ) to form a circle only.  (The general solution for any two simple closed curves is to make only the figure with the larger geometric factor of the two.)